# Handling exceptions with @MethodSource

Tags: java, arrays, junit5, illegalargumentexception

I just started to do an exercise called "Two Sum" on LeetCode and am having issues with testing.

Now, the code for the exercise looks like this:

```
public class TwoSumCalculator {
public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {

            if (numbers[j] == target - numbers[i]) {
                return new int[]{i, j};
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
}
```

}

And this is how my test looks like:

```
class TwoSumCalculatorTest {
TwoSumCalculator twoSumCalculator = new TwoSumCalculator();

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("parameters")
void findIndices(int[] expectedNumbers, int[] inputNumbers, int target) {
    int[] resultedNumbers = twoSumCalculator.twoSum(inputNumbers, target);

    assertArrayEquals(expectedNumbers, resultedNumbers);
}

private static Stream<Arguments> parameters() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{3, 2, 4}, 6),
            Arguments.of(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15}, 9),
            Arguments.of(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{3, 3}, 6),
            Arguments.of(new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution"), new int[]{3, 1, 2}, 6));
}
```

}

While the first 3 tests pass, I get the following error message with the 4th Argument:

**org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert object of type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to type [I**

What would be a better way to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to parameterize both success and failure cases in the same test, I would suggest that you test those separately. This lets you use the `assertThrows` method for asserting thrown exceptions, and avoids having to introduce logic in you test code.

Something like:

```java
class TwoSumCalculatorTest {
    TwoSumCalculator twoSumCalculator = new TwoSumCalculator();

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("twoSumParameters")
    void twoSumSolutions(int[] expectedNumbers, int[] inputNumbers, int target) {
        int[] resultedNumbers = twoSumCalculator.twoSum(inputNumbers, target);

        assertArrayEquals(expectedNumbers, resultedNumbers);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("noTwoSumParameters")
    void noTwoSumSolutions(int[] inputNumbers, int target) {
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            twoSumCalculator.twoSum(inputNumbers, target);
        })
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> twoSumParameters() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{3, 2, 4}, 6),
            Arguments.of(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15}, 9),
            Arguments.of(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{3, 3}, 6)
        );

    private static Stream<Arguments> noTwoSumParameters() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(new int[]{3, 1, 2}, 6)
            // Could add more exceptional cases here
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, or perhaps just have a separate test for cases which throw exceptions.

```
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("parameters")
    void findIndices(int[] expectedNumbers, int[] inputNumbers, int target, Class expectedException) {
        if (expectedException != null) {
            assertThrows(expectedException, () -> twoSumCalculator.twoSum(inputNumbers, target));
        } else {
            int[] resultedNumbers = twoSumCalculator.twoSum(inputNumbers, target);
            assertArrayEquals(expectedNumbers, resultedNumbers);
        }
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> parameters() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{3, 2, 4}, 6, null),
                Arguments.of(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15}, 9, null),
                Arguments.of(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{3, 3}, 6, null),
                Arguments.of(null, new int[]{3, 1, 2}, 6, IllegalArgumentException.class));
    }
```